# Office wrongly says files have come from the internet

Tags: ms-office

Office 2016 is regarding all files as having come from the internet, even if they actually have not. This problem occurs for a Standard user but not for the Administrator. I can get round the problem by going to Options/Trust Center Settings/Protected View and unchecking "Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet", but this solution obviously has risks. Searched the internet extensively but have not come across the problem. Looks like a user profile problem?

Comment: Administrator has checked  "Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet". Administrator does not get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not my ideal solution but perhaps the only one: I set up a new user profile for myself as as standard user.